# How to use b.barracudacentral list to prevent website spam on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, barracuda

Has anyone setup the Barracuda Reputation Block List (BBRL) to prevent spam from hitting a webserver?

I am a software developer and I am interested in learning how to implement a check with the BRBL to prevent bots and spammers from hitting a Web site.

Answer (score 1):

With Apache this is possible with mod_security.

There is a ModSecurity for IIS, but I have no idea if it can use DNS blocklists

Comment: You can manually enter IPs. But I do not believe their is an api.  We have a spam bot that just hammers our weberver and the ips are all over the place (proxies).  We have recaptcha, so it is more of a resource issue.  The bot uses the same physical address, but changes the name up.  Real pain

Comment: If we find a solution I will post it back on this Thread.  This has become a back burner project as other projects with higher priority have been assigned.